# cofactor in nonsigular matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A = [a_{ij}]$ be a $4 \times 4$ nonsingular matrix with $\det (A) = 5$.

We know that the inverse matrix $A^{-1} = \frac{[C_{ij}]^T}{\det A}$, where $C_{ij}$ is the cofactor of $a_{ij}$.

Find $\det([C_{ij}])$.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: det(A) is not 0, so rank(A) = 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have identified the rank correctly but it is unlikely that that can help you.

Guide:

Try to apply determinant on both sides and use the following identity to solve for $\det(C)$.

- $\det(A^{-1})=\frac1{\det(A)}$
- $\det(C)=\det(C^T)$.
- $\det(kC)=k^n\det(C)$

Your final answer should be of the form of $\det(A)^m=5^m$ where $m$ is a positive integer.

Comment: thank you for your kind guides, but I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: I can't get answer..

Comment: Can you include what you have so far?

Comment: I can't understand find det([Cij]) what really means. I'm not good at English, so my comment is late, sorry.

Comment: $[C_{ij}]$ is a matrix where its $(i,j)$-th entries consists of $C_{i,j}$, the question is asking what is the determiannt of this matrix. [here](https://www.mathwords.com/c/cofactor_matrix.htm) is some further readings on cofactor but take the question as you are given the relationship $A^{-1}=\frac{C^T}{\det(A)}$, compute the determinant of $C$. Btw, welcoem to MSE, when you post a question, try to include your attempts and your doubt rather than a typical textbook question, you will get more positive responses.

Comment: I gotcha. I saw your edited answer. Thank you for your KIND answer !